# What is the meaning of "-it" flag in angular in "ng generate component hero -it"?

Tags: angular

While learning angular, I found this command on angular site. I surfed a lot but didn't find anything.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#template-inline-or-template-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the command `ng generate component hero` it will generate 4 files like below

`heroes.component.css
heroes.component.html
heroes.component.spec.ts
heroes.component.ts`

But if you don't want to generate a template file (HTML) then you can use 
`ng generate component hero -it`

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained what `-i` and `-t` mean / stand for, and where docs live.

Answer (score 2):

You can see all option comment by `ng g c --help`
In this case it will use `-t inline-template (-t)` for your component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  template: `
    <p>
      hero works!
    </p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here are ng g c --help result:

```
ng g c --help
Generates and/or modifies files based on a schematic.
usage: ng generate c <name> [options]

arguments:
  schematic
    The schematic or collection:schematic to generate.

options:
  --defaults
    When true, disables interactive input prompts for options with a default.
  --dry-run (-d)
    When true, run through and report activity without writing out results.
  --force (-f)
    When true, force overwriting of existing files.
  --help
    Shows a help message for this command in the console.
  --interactive
    When false, disables interactive input prompts.

Help for schematic c

arguments:
  name
    The name of the component.

options:
  --change-detection (-c)
    Specifies the change detection strategy.
  --entry-component
    Specifies if the component is an entry component of declaring module.
  --export
    Specifies if declaring module exports the component.
  --flat
    Flag to indicate if a directory is created.
  --inline-style (-s)
    Specifies if the style will be in the ts file.
  --inline-template (-t)
    Specifies if the template will be in the ts file.
  --lint-fix
    Specifies whether to apply lint fixes after generating the component.
  --module (-m)
    Allows specification of the declaring module.
  --prefix (-p)
    The prefix to apply to generated selectors.
  --project
    The name of the project.
  --selector
    The selector to use for the component.
  --skip-import
    Flag to skip the module import.
  --spec
    Specifies if a spec file is generated.
  --styleext
    The file extension to be used for style files.
  --view-encapsulation (-v)
    Specifies the view encapsulation strategy.
```